# Accessing file outside build context

Tags: docker

I am aware that you cannot step outside of Docker's build context and I am looking for alternatives on how to share a file between two folders (outside the build context).

My folder structure is

```
project
  - server
     Dockerfile
  - client
     Dockerfile
```

My `client` folder needs to access a file inside the `server` folder for some code generation, where the client is built according to the contract of the server.

The `client` Dockerfile looks like the following:

```
FROM node:10-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /app

RUN yarn install --production
COPY --from=build /app ./

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "yarn", "serve" ]
```

I run `docker build -t my-name .` inside the `client` directory.

During the `RUN yarn build` step, a script is looking for a file in `../server/src/schema/schema.graphql` which can not be found, as the file is outside the `client` directory and therefore outside Docker's build context.

How can I get around this, or other suggestions to solving this issue?

Comment: if you need file on building stage you should copy it inside image. This is only way

Comment: Are you suggesting a prebuild step, where I build the project before Docker build?

Comment: you need add `COPY needed.file /server/src/schema/schema.graphql` before `RUN yarn install --production`

Comment: I can not `COPY` files outside the `client` dir, as this would result in `COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../server/ ()`

Comment: ah, I understood, you can replace needed files into `project` dir and build images from it like `docker build -t my-name ./client/`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the root of your source tree as the Docker context directory, point it at one or the other of the Dockerfiles, and be explicit about whether you're using the `client` or `server` trees.

```sh
cd $HOME/project
docker build \
  -t project-client:$(git rev-parse --short HEAD) \
  -f client/Dockerfile \
  .
```

```sh
FROM node:10-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY client/ ./
ET cetera
```

In the specific case of GraphQL, depending on your application and library stack, it may be possible to avoid needing the schema at all and just make unchecked client calls; or to make an introspection query at startup time to dynamically fetch the schema; or to maintain two separate copies of the schema file.  Some projects I work on use GraphQL interfaces but the servers and clients are in actual separate repositories and there's no choice but to store separate copies of the schema, but if you're careful about changes, this isn't been a problem in practice.

Comment: The use for the schema in this case is to generate TypeScript interfaces to get a strongly typed schema in our client as well as catching compile errors  if the client is not up-to-date to the server.

Comment: I'm actually extremely curious about this.  Is there an open-source library that generates this for you?